# PHP Secure Hashing

Tags: php

So I have a small issue over PHP. I think I've messed the foreach loops a bit. Here's the code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

class Hash{

  public function hashing($password,$hashsum)
  {
      $iter = date('sh');
      $poyl = array($iter,strrev($iter));
      foreach ($poyl as $key) {
        $itg = array('1','2','3','4','5'); # if == any array element
        foreach($itg as $v){
          if ($key == $v){ # has to be checked here
            $algo = 'TIGER128,3';
        } elseif ($key == rand(31,60)){
            $algo = 'HAVAL128,4';
          } # else
        }
      } # foreach
      return hash($algo,$password.strtok($password,'7'));
  }
}

$obj = new Hash();
print $obj->hashing('text',hash($algo,$password.strtok($password,'7')));
```

What I aim to achieve here is the following: this is supposed to be a class that would calculate semi-polymorphic hash values. In order for this kinda false polymorphism to work, I need to at least have two different hashing algorithms. (*establishing dependency and correlation with a database would be considered afterwards*).

So my problem is that I need to perform a check that would determine whether the first character (integer in this case) is equal to any of the elements in the **$itg** array (or if it's equal to any number ranging 1-30). If so, the algorithm will be **TIGER128,3**; if not (and first character of the date variable is equal to any value ranging 31-60) then algorithm applied should be **HAVAL128,4**.

The code is totally messed up. I'm using the date function to generate integers and compare them afterwards because I couldn't think of anything that fast (means this will defo be changed).

Comment: What precisely are you trying to accomplish here, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to compare what is in that array you could use `in_array()`

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
$str = '1abcdef';
in_array($str[0], $array) // Returns TRUE;
```

https://www.php.net/in_array

Comment: I want to compare whether $key is equal to 1-30 or 31-60.

Comment: Well couldn't you just do if($key >= 1 && $key <= 30) and obviously your else would be anything that doesn't match

Comment: Uh, sorry my bad. I feel reta*ded. Thanks :)

Comment: Haha, you could probably replace `foreach($itg as $v){` with the `in_array` i mentioned, it would look a deal lot cleaner